# How can I add Managed Identity to a DevTest Labs VM?

Tags: azure-managed-identity, azure-devtest-labs

I want to develop and test MSI on my development Windows VM which I created with DevTest Labs.

Going into the VM directly on *Identity (Preview)* I can change the setting but the `Save` keeps being disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve this with Azure CLI:

1. log in to Azure CLI, select Account
2. list VMs with `az vm list`
3. choose the VM to assign MSI to
4. run `az vm identity assign --name {vm-name} -g {vms resource groupname}`

checking in the portal, VM / Identity tab, the Identity has Status=`On`